# [rospy] Disable message queue

Tags: ros, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a some computation that takes a while connected to topic. I wan't that next message for computation is as fresh as possible. I have tried setting the queue to zero which results in error and setting it to one doest much help.

```
sub = rospy.Subscriber("~input",i nput_cb, queue_size = 1)
```

Test output:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1365585376.358492] msg is 0.2299852 s old!
[INFO] [WallTime: 1365585377.532643] msg is 1.3721399 s old!
[INFO] [WallTime: 1365585378.706446] msg is 1.4059465 s old!
[INFO] [WallTime: 1365585379.863709] msg is 2.5273464 s old!
[INFO] [WallTime: 1365585383.380832] msg is 2.5602341 s old!
[INFO] [WallTime: 1365585385.704427] msg is 2.5397372 s old!
[INFO] [WallTime: 1365585386.877181] msg is 2.5365553 s old!
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60373/%5Brospy%5D-disable-message-queue/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-04-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what's wrong with that code, but you can achieve what you want to do by using [rospy.wait_for_message](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/rospy/html/rospy.client-module.html#wait_for_message) instead of a Subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your delay may be coming from the publisher queue as well.  You should make sure that it is small/size 1 too.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [juancamilog](https://answers.ros.org/users/2242/juancamilog/) on 2013-08-13**:
What if your publisher is a python node? There is no queue size parameter for publishers in rospy.